# A visitor pass to the desolate earth.

Tags: story-identification, movie

This film was shown to us in school in the mid to late 1960's. It was about a young boy that lived with his family underground. The earth had become uninhabitable due to human destruction. On this boy's birthday, he received a special "pass" to the outside. All was grey and gloomy...the skies, ocean and uninhabited homes. His reaction to seeing the sky and water for the first time was "OH!! how beautiful", as his parents who remember what it used to look like look at him with sadness.

Comment: What nationality was the film? Full colour or black and white? Anything else you can remember?

Comment: Sounds decidedly French in sentiment to me.  Just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

The story sounds identical to Arthur C Clarke's short story "If I Forget Thee, Oh Earth . . . " and takes place on the moon. No idea if it was filmed or not.